# user is not allowed to do action [collMod] on [db-name.collection-name]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

I'm building an API with NodeJS, express and MongoDB. Before setting up post/put requests, I wanted to
enforce a schema
for the documents contained inside my collection and that's where the issue arises:

[user is not allowed to do action [collMod] on [db-name.collection-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDiUn.jpg)

I have also tried to add `collMod` manually but nothing changed:

[user is not allowed to do action [collMod] on [db-name.collection-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEdGm.png)

Finally, I have tried to enforce a schema via `mongosh` but encountered the same issue:

[user is not allowed to do action [collMod] on [db-name.collection-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgCUh.png)

I have tried checking the admin permissions and everything seems to be fine there too.

Comment: Please don't use images for code/errors/data/tracebacks/etc. - just copy/paste them into a code block.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the problem, you have to open your MongoDB Atlas and update Admin settings: it's not enough to have `Read and write to any database` role - you need to update it to: `Atlas admin`.

In order to do so, follow the steps:

1. Security > Database Access
2. Admin User > Edit
3. Database User Privileges > Built-in Role
4. Select `Atlas Admin` > Update User

Wait for up to 30 seconds for the changes to be saved.